# Do while loops using two variables in R

Tags: r, while-loop

Im doing a question that im kinda struggling here's the questions

"Set x to be 2 and y to be 10. Write a while() loop which prints x+y and then squares both x and y. The loop should stop when either x is greater than or equal to 40, or y is greater than or equal to 1000."

```
x <- 2
y <- 10

while(x >= 10 | y >=1000) {
  print(x+y)
  print(x^2)
  print(y^2)
  x <- x + 2
  y <- y + 2
}
```

I don't know if the code that I put up is right. I did not get any result(output). Does anyone know how to do this question using while loops while using 2 variables x and y?

Comment: sorry, not suppose to   include the last 2 code, I was doing other examples earlier on.

Comment: I think, I know what to do with the question. I will provide the correct solution on stackoverflow soon

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- 2
y <- 10

while((x < 40) & (y < 1000)) {
  print(paste("x+y =", x+y))
  x <- x^2
  y <- y^2
}
```

I think this is the correct solution

Comment: removed the prints. But I think the logic is correct because the loop breaks when either x is 40 or greater, or y is 1000 or greater

Comment: assuming x = 40 and y = 100, then `(x < 40)` becomes `FALSE` and `(y < 1000)` becomes `TRUE`. So the whole statement  `FALSE & TRUE` becomes  `FALSE` and the loop breaks